# Three.js outline mesh

Tags: three.js

How can I get outline affect the same as in [THREE.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) ?

[image]

I've tried this:

```
// child = child of my object

var outlineMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.BackSide } );

var outlineMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( child.geometry, outlineMaterial1 );
outlineMesh1.position = child.position;

outlineMesh1.scale.multiplyScalar(1.05);
scene.add( outlineMesh1 );
```

Trying to do the same as in this [example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html) ([code](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Outline.html#L114)). I'm getting completely different effect:

[image]

Same questions: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561360/three-js-outlines) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530879/how-to-add-outline-on-child-mesh-in-three-js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `wireframe`?

```
var outlineMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.BackSide, wireframe: true } );
```

Not sure if you would need `THREE.BackSide` or not.
take a look at the [parameters for MeshBasicMaterial here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshBasicMaterial)

Have you looked at the code for the editor to see how it does it?

**EDIT**

I think the editor is using a [BoxHelper](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/BoxHelper) object which creates the outline

**EDIT**

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs) is a stack question showing how to have the BoxHelper render on top.
[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/81/) is a fiddle as an example implementing the above.

Comment: the editor seems to be using THREE.BoxHelper. I have updated my answer

Comment: I've tried this, but all I can see is some front lines, nothing from back-side of the object. https://imgur.com/v5aD3Eg

Comment: see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666570/how-to-change-the-zorder-of-object-with-threejs) stack question on how to get the THREE.BoxHelper always on top.

Answer (score 0):

If you need somethink of this when user tap on mesh you can use this code :

```
  let geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(intersects[0].object.geometry);
            let mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: "black", linewidth: 10 });
            let wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, mat);
            wireframe.renderOrder = 1; // make sure wireframes are rendered 2nd
            intersects[0].object.add(wireframe);
```

[image: img]